# CSS Z-index problem with full size screen

Tags: css, mobile, z-index, layer, tablet

On my site using this snippet, I could move up a layer (the blue layers under the slider on my site  https://www.dentistcypresstexas.com/) over my slider to cover the slider buttons. On mobile and tablet screen so far it works but not on full-size screen.    Is there anyways that I can move up a layer

```
    @media only screen and (max-width: 991px) {
     .fw-container-after-slider {
      margin-top: -90px;
      z-index: 1;
        position: relative;
    }
  }
```

This is my site and appreciate any help possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the bullets removed I would suggest the following:

```
#rev_slider_1_1_wrapper .hesperiden.tp-bullets { 
 display: none;
 pointer-events: none;
}
```

However if you for some reason need the bullets to remain on screen and just sit behind your slider try the following:

```
  .fw-container-after-slider {
   margin-top: -90px; /*Edit this value for each of your @media-queries*/
   z-index: 1;
   position: relative;
 }
```

or incorporate both totally up to you :)

Comment: Thank you very much tor the help and the answer